# Can't use Blue Color Value in OpenGL 11

Tags: opengl

If i try to use `GL11.glColor4f(85, 255, 0, 1)` it works perfectly fine but as soon as i try to use the blue color value (`GL11.glColor4f(85, 255, 255, 1`) it just doesn't color at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glColor4f` expects values between 0 and 1, so that (0,0,0) is black and (1,1,1) is white. If you pass values greater than 1 they are getting clamped. Thus `glColor4f(85, 255, 255, 1)`  will produce a white color. You should instead use

```
glColor4f(85/255., 1, 0, 1) 
glColor4f(85/255., 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: thanks it works now, im new to opengl thats why i dont know a lot how the functions etc work